# Using openshift Rest Api in Django framework Python application

Tags: python, django, rest, api, openshift

i want to strarted to build an application using framework Django in python to consume Openshift rest api that the user will be able to authentication and use their resources.

the objectif of this project is to provide a web-based platform to enable Openshift users to create or interact with their online resources using Openshift web api Rest 3.0 .

Specifications of project : The required service should enable existing projects and new projects management for any user having an Openshift online account. Management includes: -Authentication and Authorization -Teams , members and subscription plan management -SSH keys management -Gear, cartridge and application management -Deployment All these capabilities must be implemented using the Openshift API and provided using a Django based web interface.

i try to read the officiel documentation through URL:https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/REST_API_Guide/index.html

but i can't find a way to start building the application and consuming this rest api. have any one an idea to start

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a new application, I suggest using v3.  The web console already has most of this functionality.  The [REST API](https://docs.openshift.com/online/rest_api/openshift_v1.html) reference should help you get started.