# Is there a way to use openshift as a oauth authenticator in my web app?

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, openshift

I am creating a web app for my company.I don't want to add a new sign up process and store the creds for our employees. We already use openshift and every one having openshift creds can login into our openshift cluster. I want to re use that creds to login into my web app.

I came to knew that openshift supports oauth 2.0 and but most of the methods available in  internet is using other identity providers like google as auth in openshift. No one guides in using openshift as identity provider in a web app. Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Research the OAuthClient object if need to authenticate a user and a way of being able to get an access token for the cluster which has same rights as the OpenShift client. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/additional_concepts/other_api_objects.html#oauthclient Or using a service account as OAuth client if only care about authenticating a user and nothing more. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/additional_concepts/authentication.html#service-accounts-as-oauth-clients

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm seeing in OpenShift 4.1's documentation on [Configuring the internal OAuth Server](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/authentication/configuring-internal-oauth.html) it looks like it may be possible to use the `/oauth/authorize` endpoint of the control-plane api.

> The OpenShift Container Platform master includes a built-in OAuth server. Users obtain OAuth access tokens to authenticate themselves to the API.
>
> When a person requests a new OAuth token, the OAuth server uses the configured identity provider to determine the identity of the person making the request.
>
> It then determines what user that identity maps to, creates an access token for that user, and returns the token for use.

The intention of this endpoint is to grant OAuth tokens specifically for use with the OpenShift cluster, not for third party applications.

Even if it ends up being possible, you'll still probably want to use the OAuth/OIDC mechanisms directly in the upstream authentication provider OpenShift is using if possible as that will provide better support and be more intuitive from an application architecture standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the openshift user api to access the identity of the user which requested an access token.

The api to call is `<api_root>/apis/user.openshift.io/v1/users/~` with a `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header.

This will give you the k8s user object containing the username and groups of the user.

You can also do this from within an openshift pod using `https://kubernetes.default.svc` as api_root, this requires you to add the ca in the pod to setup a secure connection.

The ca is mounted in any pod at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`

You can use the oauth mechanism provided by openshift to retrieve an access token using code grant.

The [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/authentication/configuring-internal-oauth.html) for the openshift oauth internals is sketchy at best, I found it helpful to find the correct urls and parameters in the dex openshift connector source code: [here](https://github.com/dexidp/dex/blob/master/connector/openshift/openshift.go) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559273/using-openshift-rest-api-in-django-framework-python-application)